# How do I draw a perfect square in ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

Pretty much what the title says. I want to draw a perfect square or at least as squarish as possible in the terminal. To be precise, I want to draw a 5x5 board but I'll manage that if I get to know how to draw a square

I calculated the ratio between the length covered by lines to cols and I got 1:2 (which I can't really guarantee) but for smaller values, the cols are larger than lines and vice versa for larger values. I tried to adjust cols by adding an offset which I either couldn't do properly or didn't work

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: @Bob__, That makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami I'm just asking the OP to elaborate on the last two sentences of their question. Is my request that bothers you or the mentioned approach?

Comment: Showing attempts while asking how to do something makes no sense. You can't show attempts at trying to find information. The problem is suitably described. In fact, even without knowing ncurses, I posted most of a solution above. (Just not willing to spend a moment to write an ncurses program for the first time to complete the answer.)

Comment: @Bob__ So the last two lines you're talking about - so I mentioned that for larger values or big squares, lines take up more length than cols right? say x is the lines, then cols is x * 2 + (x / 5) to add extra cols to fill that extra length by lines but this obviously doesn't work for smaller values

Comment: @ikegami I'm sorry but I can't find the exact comment you're talking about, just about maintaining about the aspect ratio and sig_winch. Can you explain a bit about how to get window size in pixels? Thanks

Comment: To my understanding, ncurses only draws chars, not single pixels, so even if you use the [correct function](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html), the result depends on your terminal settings. If by "eyeballing" you come up with a ratio of 2, using the formula width = height * ratio, you should get an approximation, but it still won't work very well for smaller rectangles.

Comment: @ikegami, I don't see the comment you're referring to. But I can say that curses (in general) has no concept of pixels, so you'd have to go outside the curses API for such info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.